# how to use Fuzzy look up to find the sentence in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

search term=['ISBN number on site']
the variable(column): sentence,  in MySQL table. It consist many different sentence.

the sentence I want to look for is 
"The AutoLink feature comes with Google's latest toolbar and provides links in a webpage to Amazon.com if it finds a book's ISBN number on the site."

However, When I use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable
where Sentence like "%ISBN number on site%" ;
```

I am not able to get the result. This is because the search term("ISBN number on site") is lack of one word("the") compare with the sentence.

How to change my statement in order to get the sentence I want? thanks.
Assume that We do not change the search term=['ISBN number on site']

Comment: You might want to look into using full text search with MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a simple question. Your best bet is to use some type of [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Fulltext search can be configured to have stopwords (words that are omitted from search - like the word `the`) and can have a minimum word length limit as well (words with less than certain characters long are also omitted from the search.

However, if you simply use

```
SELECT * FROM testtable
WHERE MATCH (sentence)
AGAINST ('ISBN number on site');
```

Then MySQL will return not just the record with the value you were looking for, but the records that have some of the words only, and in different order. The one you showed will probably be one of the highest ranking one, but there is no guarantee that it will be highest ranked one.

You may want to use [Boolean fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) and prepend `+` to every search word to force MySQL to return those records only that have all the search words present:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable
WHERE MATCH (sentence)
AGAINST ('+ISBN +number +on +site' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But, `on` should either be a stopword (it is on the default stipword lists) or should be shorter that the minimum word length, so should be omitted from the search expression (you will not get back any results):

```
SELECT * FROM testtable
WHERE MATCH (sentence)
AGAINST ('+ISBN +number +site' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I know that this requires alteration of the search expression, however this will get you the best results using MySQL's built-in functionality.

The alternative is to use other fulltext search engines, such as [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/11/05/sphinx-search-quick-tour-using-a-mysql-datasource/) to perform the search for you.

Comment: In case anyone need the answer.    ALTER TABLE `testtable` ADD FULLTEXT(`sentence`);
SELECT * FROM testtable 
WHERE MATCH (sentence)
AGAINST ('+ISBN +number +site' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable where Sentence like '%ISBN number on%site%' ;
```

The wildcard can go in the middle of a string too.

Comment: How would you know where to put a wildcard in a general search expression?

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there any other way to do that? As we assume that we do not change the   search term=['ISBN number on site']. this is because I use the search term as a variable, so it is hard to do if I hard-code the  search term

Comment: @Shadow you could replace each space with one. That would get you a long way I guess. Until the order starts to shift. Then maybe you'd have to split up your string based on spaces and add each word as a separate like statement (WHERE ... AND ... AND ...)

Comment: That's going to be extremely slow, since MySQL will not be able to use any index to speed up the query.